# Create Tags in Teams using Graph Beta API error -- Parameter 'tag cannot be null

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am getting error when trying to create a teams tag using beta API. Please help. Teams tag not working on Graph Explorer also.

Please help me to resolve `Parameter 'Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'tag cannot be null.').` error. 
I do not see tag property on any class to set the value.

**Task:** Create Tags using Graph Beta API 
**Error:** Code: BadRequest 
**Message:** Value cannot be null. (***Parameter 'tag cannot be null.'***)
Inner error:
AdditionalData:

**Other Teams Success operations:**

1. Reading Tags.
2. Adding Members to an existing Tag.

```cs
var teamworkTag = new TeamworkTag
{
    ODataType = "#microsoft.graph.teamworkTag",
    DisplayName = "FinanceMachTest",
    AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
       {"@odata.context", "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#teams('team-id')/tags"},
       {"@odata.count", 1}
    },
    TagType = TeamworkTagType.Standard,
    Members = new TeamworkTagMembersCollectionPage()
    {
      new TeamworkTagMember
     {
     UserId = "user-id",
     ODataType = "#microsoft.graph.teamworkTagMember"
     },
    new TeamworkTagMember
    {
     UserId = "user-id",
     ODataType = "#microsoft.graph.teamworkTagMember"
    }
    }
};

await graphClient.Teams["team-Id"].Tags
                .Request()
                .AddAsync(teamworkTag);
```

Comment: Tried to create tags in Teams using Postman and it worked. First I acquired the access token by following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service?view=graph-rest-1.0) & then referred [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/teamworktag-post?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#examples)

Answer (score 1):

Try to create tags in Teams using Postman. Acquire the access token by following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service?view=graph-rest-1.0) & also refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/teamworktag-post?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#request).